# Image stored in phone is not being displayed on screen

Tags: android, titanium

Using function in titanium for android based application.

```
StoreImage: function(args,image){
        var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,DataStorage.GetImageFileName(args));
        if(f.exists()){
            var success = f.deleteFile();
        var msg = 'DataStorage.js : StoreImage : File Exists Deleting First | ';
            Ti.API.info((success==true) ? msg + 'success' : msg + 'fail'); // outputs 'success'
        }
        f.write(image);

        return f.nativePath; 
    }
```

it takes image_detail and image as parameter and save the image to my phone, This function saves image somewhere and return a native path to me i-e `file:///data/data/com.contingent.pcc/app_appdata/158664_584.png` now issue it i need to show this image on screen but

```
var imgView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image : "file:///data/data/com.contingent.pcc/app_appdata/158664_584.png",
        width : 220,
        height : 220, //(newWidth/myImage.width)*myImage.height,
        top : 0
    });
```

`imgView` does not show the image on screen, any help

**Note:** same code works good for IPhone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2000 rep, and you haven't learned that "is not working" is a completely useless statement when asking for help with a coding problem?

Comment: @Simon Kindly don't teach me terms, you may edit it... i am doing R&D to solve my problem, don't have time to learn these things. edited it myself :)

Comment: How can I edit it when I don't know what the problem is since you have not told us?  And why should I do your work for you?  I'm sorry you're so busy.

Comment: Problem is defined very clear in title, shared my code as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the reason of the problem and fixed it myself. sharing it here if someone else get same issue.

The issue was: i was using code

```
var image = event.media;
/***umair's code'**/
//var image = event.media;
Ti.API.info(image.width + ' x ' + image.height);
var imageView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
image : image,
width : 375,
height : 500
});
image = imageView.toImage().media;
Ti.API.info(image.height + " x " + image.width);
```

for resizing the image and because of line `image = imageView.toImage().media;` file became null and did not get displayed. I just commentted this line

```
//image = imageView.toImage().media;
//Ti.API.info(image.height + " x " + image.width);.
```

and all is well.

Thanks to all who helped me.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

### if your image is located at:

```
file:///data/data/com.contingent.pcc/app_appdata/maps.png
```

then i have to do like below:

```
//FirstView Component Constructor
function FirstView() {
    //create object instance, a parasitic subclass of Observable
    var self = Ti.UI.createView();

    //label using localization-ready strings from <app dir>/i18n/en/strings.xml
    var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        color : '#000000',
        top : 10,
        text : String.format(L('welcome'), 'Titanium'),
        height : 'auto',
        width : 'auto'
    });
    self.add(label);

    var _storage = Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory;
    var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(_storage, '/maps.png');

    var av_image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
        image : file, // the image for the image view
        top : 20,
        height : 'auto',
        width : 'auto'
    });

    self.add(av_image);

    //Add behavior for UI
    label.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        //alert(e.source.text);
        //alert(sdcardDir);
    });

    return self;
}

module.exports = FirstView;
```

---